# C++: Undefined function error when I have defined the function

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a linkedlist in C++. I defined the linkedlist and node classes and the methods for the linkedlist class in the same file. Here is my linkedlist class:

```
template <class T> 
class  LinkedList{ 
    public:
        Node<T> *head;
        int size;

        LinkedList();
        void push(T data);
        T pop();
        T remove(T *target, int (*compfunc)(T *, T *));
        void clear();
        int getSize();
        void printList();
};
```

I define the push method:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push(T data){
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>;
    n -> data = data;
    n->next = this->head; 
    this->head = n;
    this->size++;   
}
```

But when I try to run the main method, I get an error saying that LinkedList::push(T data) is undefined.

Main function:

```
int main(){ 
    LinkedList<int> list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        list.push(i);
    }

    list.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

All other methods except push seem to work fine. The error I get is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         LinkedList::push(int) in linkedList-1c3a85.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: BTW, the *definition* of member function template should be in the same file where the class is defined, i.e in the *header* file itself.

Comment: I defined my class and methods in the same .cpp file. Is that what you mean? I am not using a .h file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of "read the error message."  Almost every C++ compiler with which I have interacted is very, *very* verbose.  Lots of text.  But all of the information is there.

Perhaps if we break down your error message, the problem may become more plain:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "operator new(unsigned long)",
  referenced from: LinkedList::push(int)

in linkedList-1c3a85.o ld:
  symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

The core problem is an 'undefined symbol'.  What symbol?  The `operator new(unsigned long)`.  Wait ... where is that used?  Inside of `LinkedList::push(int)`.

Okay, looking inside of `LinkedList::push(int)`, there's `Node<T> *n = new Node<T>;`.  So, the compiler does not like that line, and apparently cannot autogenerate a constructor function for you.

To wit, the issue is **not** that `LinkedList::push(int)` is not defined -- it very clearly is.  It's that the definition of how to create a new Node is missing.

Comment: Thanks! that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Stubbing out the function not supplied and a basic Node

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
};
```

compiles fine with g++ 5.4 & clang 3.8
Are you missing the definition of the node class template?